# Why isn't there a java.lang.Array class? If a java array is an Object, shouldn't it extend Object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Here is the java package-tree:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html

I read a tutorial on Java which stated that in Java arrays are objects.

Where is the array class? How comes we can make arrays like this:

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[];
char[] charArr = new char[];
int[] intArr = new int[];
```

and the arrays will inherit methods from Object; for example:

```
    byte thisByte = 1;
    byte thatByte = 2;
    byte[] theseBytes = new byte[] {thisByte, thatByte};
    int inheritance = theseBytes.length; //inherited 'length' field and some methods
    int wasntInWill = thatByte.length; //error
```

What's going on here?

**EDIT:**

As per the answers, I now know it is a `final` class in `java.lang.reflect` package.

I have now created  a package `java.lang.reflect` in my Android project and have added a class called Array.java to it. To confirm this is in the way of the original class, Eclipse gave me the error "... already exists in path/to/android.jar"

If I write out the same class as `java.lang.reflect.Array` but change the `toString()` method... this should work within my application right?

Comment: Arrays are objects, but with slightly different construction syntax then usual java objects

Comment: Wrong. It is is not 'a `final` class in `java.lang.reflect` package'.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8):

> Every array has an associated Class object, shared with all other
>   arrays with the same component type. [This] acts as if: the direct superclass of an array
>   type is Object [and] every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable
>   and java.io.Serializable.

This is shown by the following example code:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ia = new int[3];
        System.out.println(ia.getClass());
        System.out.println(ia.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

**which prints:**

```
class [I
class java.lang.Object
```

where the string `"[I"` is the run-time type signature for the class object `"array with component type int"`.

And yes, since array types effectively extend Object, you can invoke toString() on arrayObject also see the above example

```
int arr[] = new arr[2];
arr.toString();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I editted my question to get to what I was really looking for - how to override the toString() method for arrays.

Comment: You are welcome, you don't have class in your hand to change, better create a util method that accepts array object and print it in the form you want

Comment: I know that I'm just trying to see if it can be done. Of course I should try it out before I ask that, but there was a little noob part of me that was worried it would blow up my computer!

Comment: For the toString() just use Arryas.asList()

Comment: I'm aware of this also, but thanks. I wanted to see if I can make it work for my arrays normally by writing the toString() method.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I don't get how `[I` class is created and how did I get only the variable `length` for arrays? Also, why don't the compiler don't show error when I use `System.out.println(arr.length);` as array object is created at run-time?

Answer (score 10):

Arrays are a language feature - they have a specific syntax for declaring and accessing. And their class definition is hidden from you.

They have a representation in the refleciton API - `java.lang.reflect.Array`

Btw, the `length` field is not inherited from `Object`. The `.getClass()`, `.toString()`, etc. methods are inherited.

Comment: Oh so java.lang.reflect.Array is the class definition? And yeah, I meant inherited from some array Object (to prove there is an array class somewhere)

Comment: `length` field doesn't exist, there is no such field in any array. It's just java language feature that represents `ARRAYLENGTH` opcode like field. Technically, virtually each impl. has such field in the object header, though. Arrays implement 2 interfaces as well: `Serializable` and `Clonable` and publish `clone()` method.

Comment: @Ozzy No, `java.lang.reflect.Array` isn't the class definition. It is a utility reflection class that has nothing but static methods.

Comment: @Bozho Any plans to fix this answer? You've had 4.5 years.

Comment: Just to give latter comer more clarity. If you do `Integer[] array = new Integer[0]; System.out.println(array.getClass());`, you should see the class is `class [Ljava.lang.String;`, not `java.lang.reflect.Array`

Answer (score 7):

Slight elaboration of the above code segment:

```
public class ClassForName {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class theClass = Class.forName("[I");
        System.out.println(theClass.getName());
        Class superClass = theClass.getSuperclass();
        System.out.println(superClass.getName());
    }
}
```

Results:

```
C:\JavaTools>java ClassForName
[I
java.lang.Object
```

As can be seen, "[I" is the name of the class which we would call, in English, "array of int".  The class is a "full citizenship" Java class, which responds to all the methods of Object.  The only difference is that the `new` syntax is different and it doesn't support the `newInstance()` method of Class.

(The classes "[I", "[C", et al, are "pre-defined" in the JVM -- there are no .class files corresponding to them.  Java also will implicitly create, on the fly, the "[MyJavaClass;" class if you have an array of "MyJavaClass" in your program.)

Comment: Mostly correct, but: 1. Further differences are that the class is both `Cloneable` and `Serializable`. 2. The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8) and [JVM Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.3) both state that *all* array classes are created dynamically. Nothing there about some of them being built-in.

Answer (score 4):

> Why isn't there an array class?

There *are* array classes, one per element type used in the program. Both the JLS and the JVM Spec state clearly that a class object for an array is dynamically created. [JLS #10.8 'Class Objects for Arrays'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8) and [JVM Spec #5.3.3 'Creating Array Classes'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.3).

> If a java array is an Object, shouldn't it extend `Object?`

It does extend `java.lang.Object.` JLS #10.8 states clearly that 'the direct superclass of every array type is Object.'

Comment: you're a bit late, I found the class already (see answer above)

Comment: @Ozzy You didn't find the class anywhere. It isn't defined anywhere. It isn't even a single class. There is one for each primitive type, e.g. `int[]`, and one for every object type, e.g. `Object[],` `String[],` etc.

Comment: @user207421 in the JLS 10.8 it says that "an array type is not a class" . so is a dynamically created class, not a class?