# which class objects are primitive type arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't there a java.lang.Array class? If a java array is an Object, shouldn't it extend Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt)

I'd created an array say:

```
int a[] = new int[50];
```

Here, `int` is a **primitive** data type but in **java**,  *arrays* are created at run-time which means that there would be an **object** of some class.
So, I would like to know which class **object** they are and what the background process happen while making **array** object?

And one more thing I would like to know, if I would like to print the reference id of that array:

```
System.out.println(a);
```

then the output is certain kind of `[I@17182c1`
Here I know that string before the **@** is class name and after **@** is the hashcode. But which class is `[I`?
How `[I` class is created and where from I got the variable `length` which return the length of the array? I had not found class `[I` in the whole *API* of Java, then why don't compiler shows error if I write:

```
System.out.println(a.length);
```

as the class `[I` will be created at run-time?

Comment: Why is there no link to the original question here? I've seen it on other questions nominated for closure as duplicates.

Comment: I would like to know how exactly the class `[I` is created and where from the variable `length` I got? There is no class with name `[I` so how does it created and why does not the compiler shows error if I write `a.length;`?

Comment: `[I` is how Java represents `int[]` in the class's `toString` method. You can get the class using `int[].class`. See this [blog post](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html#class) for some details.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: if I can't get class `[I` then how do I only get the variable `length` neither any other variable nor any method?

Comment: @DavidHarkness The duplicate that was used as a reason to close is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt you can see it in the edit history. The reason the link is missing is similar to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/closing-as-exact-duplicate-missing-links-to-the-duplicate-questions

Comment: @MohammadFaisal - It has a class that you can get as I showed in my comment. See the duplicate question linked to by trutheality for an explanation.

Comment: Why it is still closed as I don't get the answers to my core questions. Neither I get my answer on the duplicate link.

Comment: The println, for a non-string pointer, shows the class name `[I` followed by an identifier that is, IIRC, the hash value for the object (which is derived from the address in this case) -- only the first two characters are the class name.  Array classes have names consisting of "[" followed by the obvious character to represent the primitive element type.  Array classes are subclasses of Object with all the features of other classes, other than the `new` syntax.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10674614/581994, where I address your issues to a degree.

Comment: @HotLicks: still I don't get where from the variable `length` come from and why the compiler don't show error while using it, if the class is created by JVM as per your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10674614/581994)?  Array has all the functionality of `Object` class as it extends it but what about `length`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal -- The array classes, since they are "normal" classes, can have their own methods.  Thus the array classes all define a `length` method.  (It might make sense in a way if the array classes like `[I` and `[J` (which, oddly, is the "long" array class) were subclasses of `[`, and `[` in turn defined `length`, but that's not the way the designers of Java chose to do it.)

Comment: @HotLicks: where could I find the `[` class in java-API?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal -- Like I said, that's not the way the designers of Java chose to do it.  Rather, each individual `[x` class separately defines `length`, with no superclass other than Object.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal -- And I should point out that I mispoke slightly above.  `length` is not a *method* of array objects, but rather is a read-only *field* of array objects.