# Java Array objects returns array's type instead of Array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, primitive

Before asking for help , i am really sorry if this is a duplicate question or bad question because i did not know what to search.

There is a thing that is bothering me while playing with arrays in java.
Here is code:

```
String []stt = new String[5];
stt[0].length();  //of course NullPointerException because uninitialized.
System.out.println(stt.getClass()); //it should return class of array instead of String.
```

According to above code, there is no String Object created till now and stt should be of Array type not String type ,in fact elements inside stt should be of String type.

I wanted to know what is the class of array objects and it is supposed to return class of array objects.

Comment: The explanation is quite good in the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class of what the reference is pointing to is a String array.  if you want to test to see if that reference is part of an array, then there is a special method for that, `isArray`.

```
System.out.println(stt.getClass().isArray());
```

As some other have noted, with a closer look you can see the difference in the output just using

```
class [Ljava.lang.String; // Array of String
class java.lang.String    // String
```

Comment: how come String class is associated with Array ????
we can make array of any class's objects, how they all are associated with java.lang.reflect.Array. It looks like all classes inherit Array too just like Object.

Answer (score 2):

Running this code:

```
String []stt = new String[5];
System.out.println(stt.getClass());
```

prints

```
class [Ljava.lang.String;
      ^^
```

The `[L` at the beginning means Array, the rest is obviously String. Together: String array.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `System.out.println( stt.getClass() );` actually returns an array. If you have observed keenly, the output is `class [Ljava.lang.String;` but not `class java.lang.String`. `[` denotes representation for an `Array`.

To check if the output is an array or not you can try the stament `stt.getClass().isArray()` which returns a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are not of a seperate type. So the class of an array of `String`s is still `String`. The class [`Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) is merely a collection of static methods to work with arrays and you cannot make instances of it. As pointed out in other answers you can use the `isArray` method from `Class` to determine whether the object is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `instanceof`:

```
boolean isStringArray(Object o){
return o instanceof String[];
}
```

Comment: bad coding, why not using ? return o instanceof String[]