# printing array reference variable on console

Tags: java, arrays, primitive

what does the output means...
if we print 'intarray' we get some hash code...
& same is with 'floatarray'
but if we print 'chararray' we doesn't get anything
what does the folowing data means?????

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String []aeg)
    {
        int []intarray = new int[5];
        char []chararray = new char[5];
        float []floatarray = new float[5];
        System.out.println(intarray);
        System.out.println(chararray);
        System.out.println(floatarray);
    }
 }
```

Output starts here

after printing on the console we get following output....

```
      F:\Mehnat\my sc\By me\ArrayList\2\2>javac Test.java
      F:\Mehnat\my sc\By me\ArrayList\2\2>java Test
      [I@546da8eb

      [F@6b6d079a
```

Output ends here

Comment: A guess: the `char[]` is printed as a string. Since it's all null characters, it prints nothing.

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: yeah my guess also like this, but what does '[I@546da8eb' & '[F@6b6d079a' means???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because `PrintStream.println` has an overload that takes a `char[]`. From that method's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%5B%5D%29):

> Prints an array of characters and then terminate the line.

Of course, the elements of your array haven't been initialized, so they are all the default `char`, which is `'\u0000'`, the null character. If you populate the array with visible characters, you'll be able to see a result:

```
char[] charArray = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
System.out.println(charArray); //prints "abcde"
```

The other method calls are using [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29), which prints the result of the object's `toString`. Arrays don't override `toString`, and so you see the result of the default [`Object.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) implementation:

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

As a workaround, the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class provides `toString` helper methods to get `String` representations of arrays. For example:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
char[] charArray = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'};
float[] floatArray = new float[] {1.0F, 1.1F, 1.2F, 1.3F, 1.4F};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray));  // [a, b, c, e, f]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(floatArray)); // [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
```

Comment: @YogeshVerma:  That's the string representation of the array.  The symbols mean different things (and you can look up Java Bytecode if you're really curious - that's telling me it's an integer array at some address), but instead, if you want the data, use `Arrays.toString(intArray)`.

Comment: Float []Floatarray = new Float[5];  System.out.println(Floatarray); we get [Ljava.lang.Float;@50c8d62f  it means that the array is of Float type.... but in my program if we print primitive type array, does it means that it is also a class???

Comment: @YogeshVerma I'm not totally clear on what you're asking, but all arrays are objects (reference types), including primitive arrays. The "class name" of an `int[]` is "[I", for whatever reason.

Comment: @YogeshVerma No, array types are special and their classes are provided by the JVM. See this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8546532/697449

Answer (score 7):

Printing an array of characters tries to print the array's content as a string (one character at a time). Your new array is filled with null characters which aren't printed. Try to fill it with something and check again:

```
chararray[0] = 'H';
chararray[1] = 'e';
chararray[2] = 'l';
chararray[3] = 'l';
chararray[4] = 'o';
System.out.println(chararray);
```

Should print `Hello`

Answer (score 0):

Character
Represented in 16-bit Unicode '\u0000' to '\uFFFF'.
Can be treated as 16-bit unsigned integers in the range of [0, 65535] in arithmetic operations

```
        int []intarray = new int[5];
```

By default value 0;

```
            char []chararray = new char[5];
```

new array is filled with null characters which aren't printed

```
          float []floatarray = new float[5];




    Ex:


 class Whatever {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
 char[] hello = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.'};
 String hello_str = new String(hello);
 System.out.println(hello + " " + hello_str);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because an array only contains memory addresses to each other element. It's called a "pointer" and is a programming concept that will probably thoroughly frustrate you in the future. However, printing a char[] array is overloaded as a String because a String is really just a char array.

Comment: but there not memory addresses in java. we can get only hash codes of the arrays???? i just wanna know what does ' [I@546da8eb' means?????

Comment: Well, it's kind of a memory address. It's an identity hash code: a hash code used specifically to identify things. And yes, there are memory addresses in Java, you just can't apply them. Whenever you create an object, the object does not actually "contain" all of the values within, it only points to them. As a result, you can make an object have a field of itself and you will not run out of memory due to recursion. for example, Object o=new Object(); o.setObject(o);