# Keyword length returning a value in java for an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, keyword

I see that `length` of an array is a keyword in java and that `String` has a method `length()`.

How can a keyword return a numeric value, when it is not explicitly declared to do so?

Comment: You're right to observe that this is a bit "irregular".  They do a bit of a tap-dance to explain it, but mainly it relates to the very early days of Java when it was only going to be used on set-top boxes.  Some things got started off odd and they never straightened them up.

Comment: length is not a keyword

Comment: Yep, technically `length` is a field.  Which begs the question: How can an array have a field?

Comment: @HotLicks Probably because an array is an object. I guess that arrays use `length` because arrays are objects that are supposed to feel like primitives.

Comment: @Quincunx - So why doesn't `String` have a read-only `length` field?  There's really no good argument one way or the other -- this is just the way they did it, and it got to be too late to change before there was time to do the change.

Comment: @HotLicks My argument is that an array is supposed to feel like a primitive, while a `String` is supposed to feel like a method. At least that is how I feel when I write programs. Additionally, Java has a lot of backwards compatibility, so changing the array's `length` field to a method would destroy a large amount of the backwards compatibility. So yes, we sort of agree on this. I just have my own ways of thinking about things that the language's syntax encourages (in my mind)

Comment: @Quincunx - In other words, you've convinced yourself that it's correct. ;)

Comment: (Also, if arrays have `length` and `String` has `length()`, then obviously an `ArrayList` has ...?)

Comment: How can an array have a field? Because an array is an object, and objects can have fields. Why is Java inconsistent? Because Java is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

array has a `public` `final` `int` field `length`  for [array class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt)

from [jls-10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)

> The public final field length, which contains the number of components of the array (length may be positive or zero).