# Printing an array of objects in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a phone book and filling it with entries. The entries consist of two Strings for surname and initial, and a telephone number. I'm using an array to store the entries. I'm trying to get the array to print out and I've put toString methods in each class. But when I print out i'm still getting "[LEntry;@8dc8569". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code.

```
public class Entry {

String surname;
String initial;
int number;


public Entry(String surname, String initial, int number) {
    this.surname = surname;
    this.initial = initial;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
}

public String getInitial(){
    return initial;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

void setNumber(int number){
    this.number = number;
}

public String toString(){
    return surname+ "\t" +initial+ "\t" +number;
}
}


public class ArrayDirectory {

int DIRECTORY_SIZE = 6; 
Entry [] directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE];


public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, int num) {

    int i = findFreeLocation();               

    directory[i] = new Entry(surname, initial, num);

}


public void deleteEntry(String surname, String initial) {

    int i = findEntryIndex(surname, initial);                     
    directory[i] = null;
}


public void deleteEntry(int number) {

    int i = findEntryIndex(number);                     
    directory[i] = null;
}


public int findEntry(String surname, String initial) {

    int i;
    i = findEntryIndex(surname, initial);

    return directory[i].getNumber();
}


public void editNum(String surname, String initial, int number) {

    int i;
    i = findEntryIndex(surname, initial);
    directory[i].setNumber(number);
}


public void print() {
    // TODO print array
    System.out.println(directory);
}

private int findEntryIndex(String surname, String initial) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= DIRECTORY_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        if(directory[i] != null && directory[i].getSurname().equals(surname) && directory[i].getInitial().equals(initial))
        { 
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

private int findEntryIndex(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= DIRECTORY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(directory[i] != null && directory[i].getNumber() == number)
        { 
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}


private int findFreeLocation() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE; i++) 
    {                                           
        if(directory[i] == null)
        { 
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public String toString() {

    for(int i = 0 ; i< DIRECTORY_SIZE ; i++){ 
        System.out.println( directory[i] );
    }
    return null;

}


}


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayDirectory phoneBook = new ArrayDirectory();

    phoneBook.addEntry("Bigger", "R", 2486);
    phoneBook.addEntry("Smaller", "E", 0423);
    phoneBook.addEntry("Ringer", "J", 6589);
    phoneBook.addEntry("Looper", "T", 6723);
    phoneBook.addEntry("Lennon", "B", 4893);
    phoneBook.addEntry("Martin", "M", 2121);

    phoneBook.print();

}

}
```

Comment: What do you think this `System.out.println(directory);` should do and why?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Arrays.toString();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

```
Arrays.toString(directory);
```

when you just print `directory`, which is an instance of array of type `Entry`, it doesn't override the `toString()` method the way you are expecting

---

**Also See**

- [Why isn't there a java.lang.Array class? If a java array is an Object, shouldn't it extend Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt)

Comment: I wanted the entries printed in a table fashion. However with Arrays.toString its just printing as one long line of elements. How do I adjust this?

Comment: just iterate through array in a loop and print each element in the format you want