# In Java, what are the semantics of an array as an object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

According to this question ([Is an array an object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java)), arrays are considered objects in Java.

The answers to that question mainly cite references to the language specification. My question is what methods and fields does that object have? Can I instantiate it directly (`int[] myArr = new Array<int>()`, or something similar)? In short, how does it work?

A quick search yielded no results. I see the JavaDoc for the `Arrays` object (used for sorting arrays, etc), but not JavaDoc for an `Array`.

Edit:

Just to be clear, I am NOT trying to learn to use an array for the first time. I am asking a question about the mechanics of the java language. I know I can create an array:

```
int[] a = new int[3];
```

I'm asking if there is a different way to do it - since it is an object, is there an object constructor that works? Is there documentation on the array object?

Comment: What was unclear from the answers in the question you linked? There is a syntax for instantiating arrays directly as it is.

Comment: see my edit. i'm not asking about how to make an array, i'm asking about language features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract from Bozho answer to a similar question
[Why isn't there a java.lang.Array class? If a java array is an Object, shouldn't it extend Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt)

> Arrays are a language feature - they have a specific syntax for
>   declaring and accessing. And their class definition is hidden from
>   you.
>
> They have a representation in the refleciton API -
>   java.lang.reflect.Array

Answer (score 4):

Arrays have a public final `length` attribute. They implement the `Cloneable` and `Serializable` interfaces. And of course, they inherit all methods from `Object` (`equals()`, `hashCode()`, `wait()`, etc.).

There is no class that you can use to construct an instance as you're trying in your question. The syntax to instantiate them is

```
int[] myArr = new int[someLength];
```

or, to populate them with non-default values;

```
int[] myArr = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

You can also use

```
int[] myArr = {1, 2, 3};
```

But note that you can't use this short syntax to assign a value to a previously declared variable. I.e. you can do

```
myArr = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

but not

```
myArr = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: The behaviour of an array is written into the language rather than a class +1

Comment: I know I can do it that way - I'm asking if there is a different way to do it, by calling an object constructor.

Comment: And my answer is: *There is no class that you can use to construct an instance as you're trying in your question*. Since there is no class, you can't call its constructor.

Comment: An important distinction is that arrays do have a class. The fact that you can't use it to instantiate arrays is mostly a quirk of the language/runtime rather than a consequence of the absence of such a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array in a similar way as any other Class's object.

If you aren't sure about the size of array at the time of declaration,then you can go like this---

```
class ArrayExample
{
int arr[];
public static void main()
{
//take length as input from the user
arr=new int[anylength];
//now do whatever you want to do with this array object
}
}
```

Comment: Failing to see how this answers the question.